# Passing parameters stored in Javascript Object to jQuery .load page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Ben Alman's jQuery BBQ to get the current page Querystring and Hash Values and storing them in a Javascript object using the following code:

```
var params = $.deparam.querystring();
var paramsHash = $.deparam.fragment();
```

These are all being set correctly; if I `console.log` them I get the returned values:

```
distance         "0.1"
floorFrom        "0"
floorTo          "1000"
floorUnit        "1"
ipp              "10"
locationName     "London"
location_val     "LK||001"
tab              "3"
```

Now what I want to do is pass these values to a page using a jQuery .load call.

At the moment I am using the code below

```
$('#result').load('mypage.php', { querystringData : params, hashData : paramsHash }, function()
{
...
}
```

Obviously though this is passing the data to mypage.php as: `querystringData[locationName]=London`

I need it to be passed through as `locationName=London` etc but unsure the best way to achieve this.

**Update, adding clarification, copy of comment made on answer below**

The thing I want to move away from is using querystringData and hashData in the .load call. If I was to write it all out it would look something like:

```
$('#result').load('mypage.php', { distance : '0.1', floorFrom: '0', floorTo : '1000', floorUnit : '1', ipp : '10', locationName : 'London', location_val : 'LK||001', tab : '3' }
```

I don't know how to get the values out the object and display them in the .load call like that. The other problem is that I will add and remove querystring values so I don't think it is something I can hardcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it should work, with my limited knowledge of BBQ:

```
var params = $.deparam.querystring();
var paramsHash = $.deparam.fragment();

var data = $.extend({}, params, paramsHash);

$('#result').load('mypage.php', data, function()
{
...
}
```

I believe `params` and `paramsHash` are already in the proper format, they just need to be merged.  This may not be true for hash as I'm not familiar with BBQ.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Perfect, I was completly overlooking not wrapping the data in {}, and had tried something similar, just wrapping the data in them, feel rather silly now!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jquery's `.serializeArray()` to get what you need.

```
$('#result').load('mypage.php', 
                   { querystringData : params, 
                     hashData : paramsHash.serializeArray() }, 
                   function(){}
 );
```

Comment: The thing I want to move away from is using querystringData and hashData in the .load call. If I was to write it all out it would look something like: `distance : 0.1, floorFrom: 0, floorTo : 1000, floorUnit : 1, ipp : 10, locationName : London, location_val : LK||001, tab : 3`